# Is there any way to attach latrace to an already-running process?

Tags: linux, process, debugging, glibc, trace

I want to trace a running multi-threaded process's library calls. As of 5 November 2012, there's only one way to get ltrace to fully support tracing multi-threaded processes:  you must [check out and compile an ltrace 0.7.0 prerelease](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=282068#10). So I've decided to use latrace instead. But, looking at the latrace documentation, I didn't see an option to specify a PID to attach to. Which brings me to my question:

Is there any way to attach latrace to an already-running process?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's impossible to attach latrace to a running process. The article ["Using latrace"](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/guide/html/Developer_Library_Developing_for_Harmattan_Developer_tools_Debugging_tools_Using_latrace.html) in the MeeGo 1.2 developer documentation makes it clear:

> You must restart the process with latrace for the tracing to work.

Someone should send a feature request to the [latrace mailing list](http://people.redhat.com/jolsa/latrace/).